# Mapping class A (and all subclasses) to instance of class B in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, polymorphism, guava, strategy-pattern

When implementing strategy patterny in Java, there is a common problem of mapping input data type to instance of specific algorithm.

Eg., we can create a map:

```
map.put(Apple.class, new AppleHandler());
map.put(Orange.class, new OrangeHandler());
```

and in runtime resolve correct handler for given data type:

```
Apple a = new Apple();
map.get(a.getClass()).handle(a);
```

**Question: Is there any `Map<Class<A>, B>` implementation in Guava/Apache Commons etc. libraries of such map, that would handle polymorphic types?**

E.g. for mappings above would work like that (assuming GreenApple extends Apple):

```
  map.get(Apple.class) == map.get(GreenApple.class);
```

I know that I could write my implementation traversing the hierarchy, but I'm asking about OTS solution.

Comment: Guava has [`ClassToInstanceMap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#classtoinstancemap), but this fixes the value type (to an instance of the key). I've got an implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/dhke/76fb2ed43caa5f7a5a3d) but note that this one croaks when there is ambiguity when resolving a type. Since with interfaces you essentially have multiple inheritance, getting the *most specific* type is not always possible.

Comment: Thanks for gist - I'm using similiar implementation (I think that runtime exception in case of ambiguity is acceptable). I just thought that it's quite common problem and there is some "official" solution for it.

Comment: What do you mean by an "OTS solution"?

Comment: @mfulton26 Off-The-Shelf - in the meaning "existing, ready to use solution", like a publicly available library.

Comment: @ZbigniewMalinowski, got it. I thought of "over-the-counter" but I didn't make the connection to "off-the-shelf". It seems so obvious now. Thanks. :-)

Comment: If I understood you correctly, such a map can not exist. Imagine a map that has handlers for `Serializable` and for `Comparable`. Now, you hand it an `Integer` (which is **both**!). Which handler should be selected then? The problem here is basically that inheritance in Java (due to the multiple inheritance of interfaces) does not model a [total ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

Comment: Yes, in general there can be ambiguities like @dhke pointed, but for me it could be resolved by throwing an exception. I need such a mapping for resolving implementations in strategy pattern, so it could be configured once, on startup. Ambiguity in this case would mean programmer error.

Comment: @Marco13 The Java class hierarchy is an (upper) lattice and the map is essentially a representation of a radix tree. You cannot insert every entry in from the lattice into the tree without ambiguity, but you can insert any full subtree (or parts thereof) from the lattice. So in general: Yes, you are right, it doesn't work. But you can detect the invariant violation (two possible insertion points for some class) well enough.

Comment: I think the consensus at this point is that no, there's nothing off-the-shelf.  (Certainly not in Guava.)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to simply add multiple map entries for handlers with multiple classes:

```
map.put(Apple.class, new AppleHandler());
map.put(GreenApple.class, map.get(Apple.class));
map.put(Orange.class, new OrangeHandler());
```

Some caveats to this approach include

1. If you have a lot of classes then your map may get somewhat large.
2. If external sources can define new classes of type `A` and provide them at runtime then you will need some way of registering them as well (e.g. by scanning the classpath upon initialization, providing some kind of registration API for external code to use, or add support to traverse the hierarchy if a requested key isn't in the map).

However, if you have control over the sources then you can make this "mapping" at compile-time in the classes themselves:

```
interface A {
    B getHandler();
}

interface B {
}

class Apple implements A {
    public B getHandler() {
        return AppleHandler.INSTANCE;
    }
}

class GreenApple extends Apple {
}

class Orange implements A {
    public B getHandler() {
        return OrangeHandler.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Now you can get a handler for any instance of class `A` by simply calling its `getHandler()` method. As `getHandler()` is part of the contract external sources defining new classes of `A` will also have to implement it.

If you can't change the sources of type `A` or don't want to (to [separate concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), etc.) then you can introduce a new type wrapping `A` to define the mapping using the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I'd like to solve the problem with polymorphic map; I'm aware that the problem of class mapping can be resolved in many different ways. Sorry if title was too general.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar problem via annotations like

```
@Documented @Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Handler {
    Class<? extends AbstractHandler> value();
}
```

This way I get a handler class rather than the handler itself, but this is fine in my case. You can use `Class#newInstance` or dependency injection to get the handler instance.

---

Another possibility is a lookup loop like

```
for (Class<?>  cl = givenClass; cl != null; cl = cl.getSuperclass()) {
    Class<? extends AbstractHandler> result = map.get(cl);
    if (result != null) {
        return result;
    }
}
... handle "handler not found"
```

This works for superclasses but not for interfaces. It could be expanded for them, but then you could run into [the diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem).

I did it once and the diamond problem was no problem for me, as my handlers were strictly prioritized. My final optimized solution was using a `ConcurrentMap<Class<?>, <Class<AbstractHandler>>>`, which I updated every time I encountered a new class.

Comment: Thanks, I know that it would probably look like this, I was wondering if there is a ready to use implementation in some library. Sorry if question was unclear.

Comment: @ZbigniewMalinowski Questions concerning a library are unfortunately of topic here. However, if I knew about any, I'd mention it in the answer. I guess, that the problem is not common enough (and its instances have different requirements, e.g., because of the diamond problem).